# Favicon not showing up when using include

Tags: php, html, include

Is there away that I can include the link for my favicon?

I have a `header.php` that has the link for my `ico` favicon and I want it to be included into my index file, however the favicon is not showing. I tried putting the favicon line of code directly into the `index.php` file itself and it worked, however I don't like it that way because it is messy for me.

[image: This is my Index.php][image: This is my Header.php]

Comment: You mean like the Favicon that displays on a browsers tab?

Comment: Are you sure when you include the header file, icon file path not broken ? Maybe its the file path issue, do confirm this.

Comment: Alright let me double check

Comment: Yes the path is correct. When I tried putting the main code on the index it's working. However when I included it the favicon of xammp is showing not my main logo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your Header.php change  href="Resources/favicon.png" to href="../Resources/favicon.png"
this is relational link. when you use this code direct in index it is ok. because Resources folder in same location but not work when Include because Header.php is in Includes folder. so use ../ for one step up and code work.

Comment: Thank you for helping me! But when I tried putting a 2 dots it didn't work but 1 does.